# Conditional hiding of a textbox using an expression and parameter value

Tags: reporting-services

I am using visual studio 2008 to write a reporting services report.

I am trying to conditionally hide a textbox/label on my rss report.  I have an integer input parameter the user in the form marks yes or no, but the parameter is assigned either a 0 or a 1 depending on the answer.

My current expression is:

```
=iif(Parameters!@onetime.value = 0, True, False)
```

I get error bc30455, argument not specified for parameter 'TruePart'... blah blah

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you may be declaring the parameter incorrectly.

Your parameter should look like `Parameters!onetime.Value` without the `@` sign.

Additionally, for the full statement, I'm assuming this is being used in the visibility settings.  For that property, `False` means the textbox will be visible and `True` will hide the textbox.  The expression you'll need should look like this:

```
=IIF(Parameters!onetime.Value = 0, True, False)
```

This expression will hide the textbox if the `onetime` parameter is set to 0.

Comment: Thank you!!  The '@' was throwing the thing.  Total newbie error, but I wish the visual studio error messages were more helpful..

Comment: No problem, happy to help.  If I solved your issue, please mark my answer as correct for others to find.

Comment: I did, but I'm such a newb here it says my vote doesn't get shown publicly.

Comment: @A.Nelson I think you clicked the upvote button. There should be a checkmark below the arrows, that's how you mark it the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the parameter incorrectly.

If your parameter is named `onetime`, the expression should be

```
=IIf(Parameters!onetime.Value = 0, True, False)
```

When using the expression editor, you can insert the correct syntax by selecting your parameter from the list of parameters.

Using this expression in the *Visible* property, the textbox will be visible if and only if the `onetime` parameter is set 0.